# How to use Aggregation Pipeline to process a large collection and returns all the results with no Limitation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a single large collection with tens of thousands of documents.
And I need to process the collection before displaying the result (search, sort, grouping, etc):

```
// THIS WORKS! BUT WITH LIMITATION
const pipelines = []
pipelines.push({ $match: query })
pipelines.push({ $sort: {timestamp: 1} })
pipelines.push({ $facet: {
  metadata: [
    { $group: {
        _id: null,
        total: { $sum: 1 },
        nominal: { $sum: "$total" }
     }}
  ],
  // this limits the result so it stays below the mongodb size restriction
  data: [{ $skip: start }, { $limit: count }] 
}})

// even allowDiskUse doesn't work anymore. (I'm using MongoDB 4.4)
db.collection('transactions').aggregate(pipelines, { allowDiskUse: true }, handlerFn)
```

I'm aware about the aggregation pipeline's limitation, so I use `$facet` to cut the result into part that I need to display (skip from `start` and limit the result to `count` number of documents).

My question is: How to push documents with no limit at all? Is there any workaround this limitation?

If I remove the `$facet`, `$skip` and `$limit`, it throws `MongoError: $push used too much memory and cannot spill to disk. Memory limit: 104857600 bytes`

```
// IF I CHANGE THE $facet PART WITH THIS. MONGO THROWS AN ERROR
aggregate.push({
  $group: {
    _id: null,
    total: { $sum: 1 },
    nominal: { $sum: "$total" }, // I need the sum of the "total" field
    data: { $push: "$$ROOT" } // I really need to get all the data to be put in a file
  }
})
```

Comment: You can try reducing the number of fields to be pushed instead of all fields ($$ROOT). Also, try using the `allowDiskUse` option and see if it works.

Comment: Can you not run those as separate queries?

Comment: @Joe this is exactly what I did. I had to make another query (this time with `.find()`) and calculate the sum of the documents with traditional `for(...)`. While it works, it doesn't answer the question

Comment: @prasad_: I tried to reduce the fields into a bare minimum required for my application. But eventually the data grows and you will get the same limitation error. `allowDiskUse` doesn't work anymore

Comment: See these two topics and these are important for your issues: [Aggregation Pipeline Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/index.html) and [Aggregation Pipeline Limits](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/index.html). Also, you have apipeline with a query and sort at the start of the pipeline - these could use indexes for optimization.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that $facet combines the entire result set into a single `data` array, which will be limited to 100MB.  If you run 2 separate aggregation queries instead of combining them with $facet, you can retrieve the data with a cursor and completely avoid that limit.